# Creating imagedatastore from mat file for classification problem

Tags: image, matlab

I have a mat file A. mat wit following fields:
data: 41x41x1000 
class: 1x1000
A contains 1000 41x41 images and corresponding class labels for classification.
Now I need to create an image datastore. I tried using customreader ,  ReadFcn, but its reading only the mat file.

```
imds = imageDatastore('A.mat','FileExtensions','.mat','ReadFcn',@matRead);
data=read(imds);
function data = matRead(filename)
    d = load(filename);
    data = d.data;
end
```

This returns 41x41x1000 matrix. 
I want to create imagedatastore with each of the 1000 image and its corresponding class. 
I dont want to use imwrite and reading from disk after creating subfolders.
I am sure there will be a way in matlab to do this.
Please help as I am relatively new to matlab.

Comment: I am having the same issue if you found a solution please share it with the community.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have all of my "images" stored as separate .mat files. I point to the image directory using the first parameter (not A.mat).

```
imds = imageDatastore(my_img_dir, 'FileExtensions', '.mat', 'ReadFcn', @matRead);
```

Use ...,'IncludeSubfolders',true,'Labelsource','foldernames'... if you're images are in subfolders with each subfolder name corresponding to a separate class